# How do I vectorize using a lookup?

Tags: r

I am a newbie who's been doing R for a few days now. Just can't seem to figure out how to implement a lookup. Suppose I have the following 2 dataframes:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 5:1, z = letters[1:5])
dflookup <- data.frame(x = 3:4, a = 10:11)
```

I was looking at doing something like this:

```
df.matches <- dflookup[which(dflookup$x %in% df$x),]
df['newcol'] = df.matches$a #if matches are missing then it should insert NA
```

Currently the error I am getting is that the number of rows in the replacement is less than the original which makes sense but I can't figure out how to stick in an NA to rectify this or maybe some other way to do it? Can someone give me a tip on how to do the lookup correctly?

Comment: I think you need `df$newcol <- dflookup$a[match(df$x, dflookup$x)]` ?

Comment: That's it! Please put it as an answer so I can give you credit!

Comment: I think this has been asked before, finding a right duplicate to close this question.

Comment: Would have never found the other one by its title. Thanks for linking!